# Fire MouseClick on TableLayoutPanel?

Tags: c#, winforms, tablelayoutpanel

I have a TableLayoutPanel with some controls added as Label and PictureBox. Now I am trying add a Handler to MouseClick to this TableLayoutPanel. If I do remove these controls Label and PictureBox the Handler is fired right, but with controls doesn't. I tried send these controls go to back, example: `Label.SendToBack()` but it doesn't works too. I think the problem is with the controls Label and PictureBox because without them  works fine.

How could I solve this ?

```
void initComponents(){
            IList<Mesa> lista = mDAO.findAll();
            if (lista.Count > 0){
                foreach (Mesa mesa in lista){
                    customPanel = new TableLayoutPanel();
                    customPanel.MouseClick += cms_MouseClick; //mouseclick of customPanel
                    customPanel.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None;
                    customPanel.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 128);
                    customPanel.Size = new Size(100, 100);
                    customPanel.Name = Convert.ToString(mesa.id);

                    //label mesa
                    numMesa = new Label();
                    numMesa.Font = new Font(numMesa.Font.Name, 12, FontStyle.Bold);
                    numMesa.Text = Convert.ToString(mesa.id);
                    numMesa.SendToBack();

                    //picturebox
                    picture = new PictureBox();
                    picture.Anchor = (AnchorStyles.Top | AnchorStyles.Bottom | AnchorStyles.Left | AnchorStyles.Right);
                    picture.Image = IguanaBar.Properties.Resources.mesabar;
                    picture.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
                    picture.SendToBack();

                    //label aviso
                    aviso = new Label();
                    aviso.Anchor = (AnchorStyles.Right);
                    aviso.Font = new Font(aviso.Font.Name, 6, FontStyle.Bold);
                    aviso.Text = "LIVRE";
                    aviso.ForeColor = Color.Green;
                    aviso.TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
                    picture.SendToBack();

                    //add components
                    customPanel.Controls.Add(numMesa);
                    customPanel.Controls.Add(picture);
                    customPanel.Controls.Add(aviso);

                    //add panel a panel principal                    
                    panelMesas.Controls.Add(customPanel);
                }                
            }            

            //popup menu
            cms = new ContextMenuStrip();
            cms.Items.Add("Vender");
            cms.Items.Add("Finalizar");
            cms.Items.Add("Trocar");
        }
```

Comment: When you click a `Control` the click doesn't pass to its parent, so when you click on the `Label`, the `TableLayoutPanel` doesn't receive the click. You can handle `Click` event of those child controls using the same logic which you want to use when you click on parent control. But before going on the way which you are going you should have a good answer for this question: *Why do you try to simulate what `DataGridView` can simply do for you?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change

```
 numMesa.SendToBack();
 picture.SendToBack();
```

to

```
  numMesa.MouseClick += cms_MouseClick; //mouseclick of customPanel
  picture.MouseClick += cms_MouseClick; //mouseclick of customPanel
```